# How to I take my current starting location and measure the distance after/during a run, using Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, mapkit

Currently I have the following, its really basic but whenever I run the application it has this random initial jump, so it will start at 0 then jump to a random distance then count up normally, I've looked at a bunch of tutorial but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MyMap: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!

let mapManager = CLLocationManager()

var startLocation: CLLocation!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapManager.delegate = self
    mapManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    mapManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()





    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {

    mapManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[0]

    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake( 0.01, 0.01)

    let myLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)

    MyMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)




    self.MyMap.showsUserLocation = true

    if (startLocation == nil) {
        startLocation = locations.first
    }
    else {

        let newLocation = location.distance(from: startLocation)
        distanceLabel.text = String(newLocation)

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location manager does a couple of rather odd things that you have to allow for.

First, it caches the last location it recorded, and when you first ask for location updates, it may give you a "stale" location (a reading with a very old timestamp.) I haven't looked at the data you get for several OS releases, so I don't know if it still does this. If it does, the way to fix that is to check the date on the location updates you get and reject any that are more than a couple of seconds old.

Second, the first readings you get may be wildly inaccurate. It takes the GPS a while to settle down. You can deal with This problem by checking the horizontal accuracy reading. This is expressed in meters, and smaller is better. It's actually a margin of error. (The name accuracy is a bad choice of words if you ask me.) So you might decide to reject readings with a horizontal accuracy > 100 meters, or 50 meters, or something like that.

If you do those 2 things then you should avoid a huge jump at the beginning. However, you may also find that when you go into areas with poor GPS signal, your horizontal accuracy drops below your threshold and you stop getting updates. You might need to create logic that handles that case too.